# LTspice XVII very buggy behaviour with IR2110

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to simulate IR2110 high and low side driver, but I get very odd bugs - simulation result varies just by changing simulation stop time or saving, exiting and then reloading program. I am using [this](http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/) library for both IR2110 and mosfets. Is there a better library? Also - why in some examples of such driver there are two capacitors - one polarized and another not? This is my drawing:[image]

Comment: C4 is 5000 µF.  I don't know if that's what causes the issue, but it's way too high.

Comment: Minimum value is 300uF - anything lower and I get poor gate output wave.

Comment: But again - I cannot even test this properly - after 10-200ms I get "Time step too small"

Comment: @RiDi That's absurd. The bootstrap capacitor is usually `100n...1u`. Change it to `1u` and try again. You should also add a `.model` to your diodes, or use ones from the database. Try `BAT54`, for example. Also, your half-bridge with load is not very well connected...

Comment: Fix the circuit and take a look here https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/ir2110-ltspice-download-and-setup.153986/#post-1328179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you really **intend** to make a short through R3 every time the driving signal is high? This cannot work. The IR2110 does not invert the low side switch, see figure 1 on page 6 in the DS. To drive the high side, you need the high side off and the low side on, in the first place, to charge the bootstrap cap, which will supply power to the high side when it's time comes. Your HIN should be **180 degrees out of phase** with LIN, I guess...

Comment: thanks. did not know that. I thought they could be both operated at same time